# Read a selected text from every line using python

Tags: python, file

I have a file which contains string like

```
[{"resourceId": "sid-14E51598-BEE7-45E0-9974-A38B07CE6892"}]
[{"resourceId": "sid-A5B57DEB-C024-4D89-AD99-86FC340A6742"}]
[{"resourceId": "sid-3775C783-4491-44B9-904C-1763C080E9C6"}]    
[{"resourceId": "sid-8F636B07-3010-4D27-9E9B-08DB1D25AC96"}]
```

I want to get only `sid-8F636B07-3010-4D27-9E9B-08DB1D25AC96` from every line using python. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is for example named test.txt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

with open('test.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        data = json.loads(line)
        print data[0]['resourceId']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split each line according to double quotes and then print the third index.

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split('"')[3])
```

Comment: [Accept an answer which helps you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have dicts inside lists which can be parsed with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(literal_eval(line)[0]["resourceId"])

sid-14E51598-BEE7-45E0-9974-A38B07CE6892
sid-A5B57DEB-C024-4D89-AD99-86FC340A6742
sid-3775C783-4491-44B9-904C-1763C080E9C6
sid-8F636B07-3010-4D27-9E9B-08DB1D25AC96
```

Or use `json.loads` if all the items are wrapped in double quotes:

```
from json import loads

with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(loads(line)[0]["resourceId"])

sid-14E51598-BEE7-45E0-9974-A38B07CE6892
sid-A5B57DEB-C024-4D89-AD99-86FC340A6742
sid-3775C783-4491-44B9-904C-1763C080E9C6
sid-8F636B07-3010-4D27-9E9B-08DB1D25AC96
```

If you are not always sure of the key name just access the values:

```
from json import loads
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(list(loads(line)[0].values())[0])
```